# source ~/.bashrc results in ln: failed to create hard link '/dev/raw1394': File exists

Tags: 16.04, bashrc

i updated my bashrc file. when i try to save it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518127/how-do-i-reload-bashrc-without-logging-out-and-back-in I get the error

```
ln: failed to create hard link '/dev/raw1394': File exists
```

I am running a docker image if that helps. Below is the output of `cat ~/.bashrc`

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# don't put duplicate lines in the history. See bash(1) for more options
# ... or force ignoredups and ignorespace
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
#if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#fi
ln /dev/null /dev/raw1394
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/
```

Comment: Run `cat ~/.bashrc` and post it into your question!

Comment: Why do you have `ln /dev/null /dev/raw1394` in there?

Comment: @George i have updated my post

Comment: @George i don't know... I was experimenting with the environment variables on my docker image. Is it not supposed to be there ? I guess I could just delete this image and re-load another one and I should be able to source the bashrc file ? I only remember appending 

**export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow** and 
**export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/**

Comment: Ok I think you know what the issue is then, remove that and it aught to be ok!

Comment: @George the ln /dev/null /dev/raw1394 was already in the bashrc file. Does it have something to do with docker ?

Comment: I think it's an issue with `libdc1394` which is solved with `[sudo|] ln /dev/null /dev/raw1394`, see [here](https://enlook.wordpress.com/2015/01/29/error-ctypes-error-libdc1394-error-failed-to-initialize-libdc1394/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689304/ctypes-error-libdc1394-error-failed-to-initialize-libdc1394). So since you have (the link) it just remove that line and you should be fine!